# Google cannot fetch my Domain or IP, simply cannot be read by google

Tags: http, iis, dns, reverse-dns

I have a domain: https://tayninh.gov.vn which config in Microsoft Server (IIS 7.5 & DNS Manager).
Ive checked all MX Record/Dns records but not found anythings wrong.
It simply cannot be read by google. Please help me.

Comment: https://vnnic.vn/whois-information says that the authoritative DNS server is dns1.tayninh.gov.vn - which is in the domain itself; is that allowed? - and that server is not responding to dig requests for me.

Comment: Thanks, what should I do now? Ive tried to use Cloudflare DNS but not recognized by them.